# Can I use react testing library with jest to do integration tests?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jestjs, automated-tests, integration-testing, react-testing-library

My app has a React front-end and ASP.NET core Web API back-end. I've built some unit tests (i.e. which stub out `fetch()`) with react-testing-library.

Now I want to do an integration test calling the real back-end API over HTTP. There are lots of standalone API testing tools I could do this, but then I'm still not testing the interface between the React components and the server.

Is there any reason I shouldn't simply write jest tests that don't stub out `fetch()`, and achieve a real end-to-end test? this seems quite obvious to me but I haven't seen any articles discussing it.

Comment: You can use the more general https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/intro for *"unit, integration, and end-to-end tests"* per the FAQ. Using the React version seems a bit too coupled to the underlying technology for an E2E test. Jest is just a test runner, it doesn't really care what type of tests you're writing - you could also use it with e.g. [WebdriverIO standalone](https://webdriver.io/docs/setuptypes.html#standalone-mode).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW after getting the first few tests going it seems to be a pretty successful approach. I have been able to "almost" remote-control the UI (by which I mean it's not actually running in a browser, but it is using my React components) without having to learn or set up selenium.

The biggest headache was JSDOM's implementation of fetch (which in their defence probably wasn't meant to do this kind of thing). I ran into lots of problems with cookies and CORS so I used node-fetch instead and this gave me much more control over the HTTP requests I was generating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do what you're proposing (not mocking `fetch` and hitting your actual backend) with RTL. Hopefully, though, you do have a testing database set up so you don't wind up messing with your production data.

Your question seems to use end-to-end and integration interchangeably, which isn't uncommon.

"Integration" is broad and can happen on different levels:

- integration of multiple React components and hooks, but with services and the API mocked
- integration of the front and back-end, with the database mocked and the browser simulated with JSDOM (as with RTL)
- integration of the whole stack, but with the browser simulated

You could call the last two end-to-end as long as you're aware that RTL doesn't quite give you the realism guarantees of a browser automation library, although the [user-event](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event) package helps.

Although use cases might encourage you to do otherwise, as a rule of thumb, I suggest using RTL primarily for front-end code, possibly integrating multiple components, but with the backend mocked.

If you want to do API testing (again with varying degrees of depth), prefer writing Jest/supertest tests for that part of the stack separately.

If you want to do end-to-end testing, I suggest not mocking anything and using a browser automation library like Playwright. These tests don't need to be deep, just there as a safety check on the other tests.

The "RTL with unmocked backend" pattern isn't exactly *wrong*, and may be a good fit for certain situations, but feels less desirable in general than the patterns described above.